# Plotting function with imaginary axis

Tags: plot

I want to plot a function `f(x)=x^8-5x^7+8x^6+13x^5+24x^4+8x^3+32x^2-12=0` with imaginary axis. I have no clue how to do such thing. Here is an example. 
[image]

The photo is from youtube channel [walch labs](https://youtu.be/T647CGsuOVU?t=126). Here the plotted function is `f(x)=x^2+1` and the `z` axis is imaginary.

Comment: The case `f(x)=x^2+1` is doable (and has been done, perhaps not explicitly) because we all know how to use hyperbolic functions (provided my interpretation of the question applies). Your function will be much more messy. I would not use pgfplots to plot its zeros  if this was my first attempt of using the package.

Comment: Can you give me link to an example post where simple hyperbolic functions such as ```f(x)=x^2+1``` is plotted with imaginary axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection of the surface with the x-z plane can be parametrized with the hyperbolic functions. Why? The surface in real coordinates can be parametrized by `(x,1+x*x-z*z,z)`. Now we need to solve `z*z-x*x=1` in order to have the second component 0, so an obvious choice is `z=cosh(t)` and `x=sinh(t)`. In principle, you can parametrize the full thing with `cosh` and `sinh` but here is an illustration in which the intersection gets clipped and filled with a grid (in 3d, of course).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[overlay] (-5,10) coordinate (TL) (5,10) coordinate (TR); 
 \begin{axis}[view={210}{30},hide axis,
    axis equal image,
    width=15cm]
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,
    domain=-2:2,domain y=0:2,z buffer=sort,
   point meta=-z,clip=false]
   (x,1+x*x-y*y,y);
  \path (2,5,0) coordinate (L)  (-2,5,0) coordinate (R);
  \clip plot[domain=-1.317:1.317]   ({sinh(\x)},{0},{cosh(\x)})
  -- plot[domain={sqrt(3)}:2] (\x,\x*\x-3,2) 
  -- plot[domain=2:0] (2,5-\x*\x,\x) 
  -- (3,5,0) -- (TL) -- (TR) -- (-3,5,0) 
  -- plot[domain=0:2] (-2,5-\x*\x,\x) -- cycle;
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
   \draw (-8,0) grid[step=5mm] (8,10);
  \end{scope}
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]